# Make a TornadoFX window always on top

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to make a little virtual keyboard written in Kotlin and I'm using TornadoFX which is great but not perfectly documented yet. I found out that JavaFX has a method for this particular purpose which is something like `stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` but I could'n find the equivalent for tornado. Also I would like the window to not request the focus when it is clicked so that the text keeps on being typed in another window.

To summarize, I need my window to:

- be always on top of other windows
- not request focus when it receives a click

Comment: TornadoFX is just a layer on top of JavaFX, so every function call from JavaFX is still valid. Call `currentStage?.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` from any View :) Not sure how to avoid receiving focus on click, but if it works in JavaFX it will work in TornadoFX as well.

Comment: Ok I will try this out, thanks a lot @EdvinSyse

Answer (score 0):

In your main `View` class `init` block, add `primaryStage.isAlwaysOnTop = true`.